# PHP & MySqli - How to search and work on 'LIKE' even there is additional characters on the textbox?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I search the like value or similar value even there is an additional characters on the textbox? right now i cant get rid of the additional characters because the are fixed.

here is the sample image

[image]

so that is my textbox now i want to get the similar value like the `44444444`
 and here is my table content

[image]

and here there is the similar and like values

here is my code

```
  <form method="POST" action="">


         <input type="text" name="id" id="card-code" value='<?php echo $code ?>' class="form-control">

   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Data" class="btn btn-primary"></input>

</form>



 <?php 

        $connection =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
        $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'inflightapp');

        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
          $id = $_POST['id'];

          $query = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE code LIKE '$id' ";
          $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
          {
            ?>
            <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></input>
              <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount'] ?>"></input>
            </form>
            <?php
          }

        }

         ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: _Side note:_ `input`-elements are self closing: `<input type="..." />` so it shouldn't have a `</input>`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , no worries sir this is just a project from school okay ill change the input right away.. but do you have any solution sir? thank you very much

Comment: What is the actual value you are receiving?

Comment: @SalmanA , there's nothing i received when i click the submit button but when i remove the other characters .. i get the correct output.

Comment: Just a heads up; you should _never_ knowingly write insecure code. Before you know it, you will copy some working "test code" in a real project, not thinking about it being unsafe. Also, using unescaped values like that has other issues than security. If the string would contain some characters (ex. a single quote or ends with a backslash), your code will fail.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , ill take your advice sir thank you,

Comment: @MagnusErikssonm but for now can you help me with my problem :(

Comment: If everything aside from the code you are looking for is fixed, can you just remove the bits you don't want, like "$id = str_replace("QR CODE: ","",substr($_POST['search'], 0, -6))"

Comment: @Stephen can i do that? can you please check your code again sir" why there is $_POST['search'] there?

Comment: I made the assumption that $_POST['search'] contained "QR CODE: 444444444 | 123", so my snippet would just leave "444444444".

Comment: @Stephen did not work sir :(

Comment: http://codepad.org/zQInH7eD

Comment: @Stephen hey thanks it works but the value is static what if i change it to another value 44444444 is static sir :(

Comment: You can change 444444444 to anything you like, my snippet just chops the front off, and then the end, leaving the bit in the middle: http://codepad.org/znDwzTnM

Comment: @Stephen: Your code will not work if the pin has more or less number of characters.

Comment: http://codepad.org/QBgN9ML1

Comment: @obitouchiha Is the input always the exact same format? If not, how may it look in other cases?

Comment: If input gets changed then test case will get failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with the php string functions to get the exact string as:

```
$str = ltrim( strstr("Qr Code: 444444444 | 123",":"),":");
$strFinalString = trim(substr($str,0,strpos($str, "|")));
echo $strFinalString;
```

Please suggest if this code requires some optimisation.

Comment: Yes, I agree, which is why I didn't submit mine as an answer.  The OP did say, however, that the input never changes.

Comment: @Mac, this code works well i just adjust a little bit of it and it worked fine ! thank you !